# Preguntar por un str dentro de una lista que esta dentro de otra lista

Tags: python, lista, condiciones

Tengo una lista llamada `grupos_agregados` y quiero preguntar por medio de un if si un nombre esta dentro de esa lista:

`grupos_agregados = [['Varias', 4], ['Ecuaciones', 4]`

```
def agregar(nombre, grupo):
    if nombre not in grupos_agregados[todos las listas internas][0]:
        grupos_agregados.append([nombre, grupo])
```

Si quisiera agregar `agregar('Ecuaciones', 7)`, no me dejaria porque ya existe un `Ecuaciones` dentro de `grupos_agregados`

Más si quisiera `agregar('Calculo', 7)` SI, ya que no existe un `Calculo` dentro de `grupos_agregados`

¿Como puedo hacer eso en una linea de codigo sin la necesidad de llamar a un `for` que llame a cada uno de los elementos de `lista` ?

Comment: Y que problemas te da tu código?? Por favor lee [ask] 0ara que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida

Comment: No sé que quieres hacer, pero primero de todo creo que lo que necesitas es un diccionario en vez de una lista

Answer (score 1):

#### Solución

Como te han dicho en los comentarios, tu mejor opción es un diccionario. Un diccionario nos permite relacionar un valor con otro.

En tu caso convendría que la clave sea el nombre de la materia y el valor el grupo.
Un ejemplo de dicho diccionario sería:

```
{'Varias':4, 'Ecuaciones':4}
```

Podemos saber si una clave está en un diccionario evaluando la condicion `clave in diccionario`, lo cual devuelve True si la clave está en el diccionario.

Podemos usar todo esto para crear una función que verifique si el nombre dado está como clave del diccionario, y si no lo está, crear dicha clave.

```
grupos_agregados = {'Varias':4, 'Ecuaciones':4}

def agregar(nombre, grupo):
    if nombre not in grupos_agregados:
        grupos_agregados[nombre]=grupo
```

#### Más información

Seguramente quieras saber más cosas sobre el diccionario, ya que probablemente trabajarás con el en otros aspectos. Te recomiendo los siguientes links para informarte:

- https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict (Documentación oficial)
- https://ellibrodepython.com/diccionarios-en-python